# Toggle lodash orderBy ascending and descending

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a method in my vue.js that is sorting my items by the date they registered in ascending but what I really wanted is for 1 unique button to be clicked and toggle between ascending and descending.

JS

```
sortAsc(customers) {
  // Click and sort registered customers by ascending
  let sort = _.orderBy(this.customers, 'registered', 'asc')
  this.sortedCustomers = sort
}
```

How can I make the above so when I click 1x sorts by ascending and click 2x sorts by descending?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you pass one more parameter to your function? If you want a single button then add some flat which will store current order of sorting. And toggle it when your function is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another property to the object (`sortOrder`) that saves the current sort order. Toggle it when you call the function - use `asc` if it's `undefined` or set to *desc*:

```
sortAsc(customers) {
  this.sortOrder = this.sortOrder !== 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'

  const sort = _.orderBy(this.customers, 'registered', this.sortOrder)
  this.sortedCustomers = sort
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.sortBy**, it will always return an ascending list:

```
_.sortBy([2, 3, 1], function(num) {
    return num;
}); // [1, 2, 3]
```

But you can use the **.reverse** method to get it descending:

```
var array = _.sortBy([2, 3, 1], function(num) {
    return num;
});

console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(array.reverse()); // [3, 2, 1]
```

Or when dealing with numbers add a negative sign to the return to descend the list:

```
_.sortBy([-3, -2, 2, 3, 1, 0, -1], function(num) {
    return -num;
}); // [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3]
```

Under the hood .sortBy uses the built in .sort([handler]):

```
// Default is ascending:
[2, 3, 1].sort(); // [1, 2, 3]

// But can be descending if you provide a sort handler:
[2, 3, 1].sort(function(a, b) {
    // a = current item in array
    // b = next item in array
    return b - a;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this, is by having a variable which keeps changing its value on each call

```
let toggler = true;
```

Then in your sortAsc function assign the value "asc" or "desc" based on this toggler

```
sortAsc(customers){
      // Click and sort registered customers by ascending
     toggler = !toggler ;  //change the value based on the current value 
     let order = !toggler ? "asc": "desc";
     let sort = _.orderBy(this.customers, 'registered', order)
     this.sortedCustomers = sort
}
```

I hope this helps